# Linked list with two pointers trying to catch a loop

Tags: python, linked-list

Hello I need help on detecting a loop and returning `False` on a linked list but first, let me explain how this linked list looks like:

This would be the node class:

```
class Node:

        def __init__(self, next = None, stairs = None):
            self.next = next
            self.stairs = stairs
```

Comment: So you need to find a loop in a graph. I think [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-function-to-detect-loop-in-a-linked-list/) might be of help.

Comment: Does 'not being allowed to change the Node class' mean that you cannot, for an instance do 'node.visited = true' for some node? - I.e. are you allowed to modify instances of Node?

Comment: Yes, you cant do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your step size doesn't change the code will, once it has visited a node twice visit it over and over again. This is due to the fact that it will make the same decisions at every node that follows the repeated node. Thus you only have to detect if (at least) one node has been visited twice. Two common ways of doing this are the following:

1. Count how many nodes there are in the linked list (i.e. take a new variable `N=0` and increment it on every run of the first loop of the `play` function). Then in the second loop count how many nodes have been visited. Once that number is larger than N you know that at least one node has been visited at least twice and therefore you have detected a circle and need to `break` out of the loop (or `return`).

```
def play(first, step):
    '''(LinkedList, int) -> bool
    '''
    # locates the end_node
    end_list = first
    found = False
    # Used to find Node population
    N = 0
    while end_list.next != None and found != True:
        if end_list.next == first:
            found = True
        else:
            end_list = end_list.next
        N = N + 1
    stepcount = 1
    count = 1
    current = first
    winner = False
    loop = False
    # Goes through the linked list
    while current != None and winner != True and loop != True:

        # If count == step, then we check if we are at the last square or  
        # else if we are on a stairs then we may use them. 
        # If none of them are found then we itterate normally making count back to 1.
        # If stepcount passes the overall N (population of all the nodes),     then it will detect a loop

        if stepcount > N:
            loop = True #one node has been visited more than once so there is a loop
        elif count == step:
            if current == end_list:
                winner = True
            elif current.stairs:
                current = current.stairs
                count = 0
            else:
                current = current.next
                count = 0
            stepcount = stepcount + 1
        else:
            current = current.next
            count = count + 1
    return current == end_list
```

2. Keep track of which nodes you have visited: To do this you can just add a new attribute to each node you visit (i.e. `node.visited = True`). At the beginning (i.e. in the initial loop) of your function `play` you'd want to make sure that the structure is clean, i.e. set `node.visited = False`. If you don't want the nodes to be changed after the function play has been called you can just delete them in another loop at the end (i.e. `del node.visited`).

Comment: For 1 a couple question. What do you mean by this "Then in the second loop count again how often it has been executed. "? And this for ". Once that number is larger than N you know that at least one node has been visited at least twice and therefore you have detected a circle and need to break out of the loop (or return)." Do I create another counter?

Comment: I have added an example of what you'd probably want to add to the second loop

Comment: Almost: 1) You can do `if stepcount > N:` unconditionally (i.e. not nested) to break earlier - The detection of a loop does not depend on the stepsize. 2) `N = N + 1` needs to be in the body of the while-loop (maybe just an indentation error?) - The way it is right now always results in N=1 independent of the list

Comment: Oh - and I missed the fact that you'd better increase `stepcount` unconditionally as well (i.e. increase it outside of the if)

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Looks fine now.

Comment: Hello, after further testing I realised that this wouldn't work. A basic counter example would be: new_board = create(8,{}) (This is basically a board with 8 squares no ladder or snakes). Now we put play(new_board, 3), as in the step size is 3, then it will start from 3 and go to this order 3-6-1-4-7-2-5-8, as you can see N=8, and stepcount would also be 8. So it would return False, but it should return True because we got to the end board.

Comment: In thinking about it you are right - It is not ok to count the nodes that are skipped. So your first version (counting only when the next node was found according to the stepsize) was right. Example: Consider 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 and then from 5 to 1. Then if you start at 1 and stepsize is 3 the first transition is from 1->4 then 4->2 and finally 2->5 so clearly more then 5 nodes have been seen. Sorry about that ;)

Comment: Like when stepcount was inside the count == stepsize: condition?

Comment: Yes - That is the right way to go because we only care about the nodes that we have visited according to stepsize. Again apologies - It is far too early in the morning. - I have edited my answer to make the proposed version clear. Wish I could easily test it ...

Comment: Sorry for the intrusion. Still very grateful that you helped me but on the off chance my class mates sees this, I don't want them seeing my code :/.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Use some sort of node or path disabling, as I suggested last time.  Your posting doesn't mention why that doesn't work for you.
2. Count how many steps you've taken and compare against the node population (call it N).  If you take **n** steps without reaching the end, then you're in a loop.
3. Try to construct a new list that contains the steps from where you start to the final node.  This is a strictly linear linked list, such as START -> 3 -> 6 or START -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 ...  If you try to add a node that's already in this linked list, then you have a loop.

Comment: For 1, I had to mutate my linked list and It got really confusing when I had to unmutate it. I think the best way to do this if there was a way to clone my linked list, i dunno. For number 2 I don't really understand what you mean. How do I compare against the node population?

Comment: For 2) you can do the following: In your first loop in play() count the number of nodes you have visited in a variable N. Then count the number of steps in the second loop. If that number is ever larger than N then you must have visited at least one node twice since there are only N nodes to visit.

Comment: I thought about 2 more. I think you mean that the population is the length of the linked list and I should return False if my steps are longer than the length. The problem with this would be, what if the linked list is crazy with bunch of stairs and eventually you'll reach the end of the node but after numerous amount of steps (it is a circular linked list). So I'm pretty sure this would work for most cases but not for all. If that what you were trying to say if I was understanding properly

Comment: Yes, but if your step size doesn't change you will, once you have visited a node twice, visit it over and over going the same path. - Thus it is sufficient to detect if you have a visited a node more than once.

Comment: Okay im trying it

Comment: (1) Yes, you can clone a list.  Write a recursive routine that clones the head node, and then recurs to clone the rest of the list.  (2a) Yes, the population is the quantity of nodes.  This is simply the length of the input list from which you created the linked list.  (2b) This *does* work for all cases in the paradigm you've described.  If you take N+1 steps with only N nodes, you *must* have hit at least one node twice.  This means that you have a loop.